# How to Trigger an Event using VFX Graph

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm beginner level with Visual Effects Graph on Unity.
I want to be able to toggle on and off a VFX, but
I'm having difficulty understanding how to trigger that to happen
( and cannot find documentation on this )

[Screenshot of current VFX Graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/houIc.png)

I understand pressing 'spacebar' creates an Event and Event name ( OnPlay by default )
but how do I utilize this feature in C#?

Any help will be greatly appreciated. Even pointing me to correct documentation.

Comment: I discovered my answer. For anyone curious like me -- make sure to import UnityEngine.vfx into your C# script ( using UnityEngine.vfx; ) then declare your vfx variable as "public VisualEffect <nameofvfx>"  THEN you're going to use SendEvent method to toggle on/off ( Example: nameofvfx.SendEvent("nameofevent"). Hope this helps someone!